# How to click on a link inside the data-content of a pop-over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added links into popover data-content. How can I perform a click() action on the links I have placed inside the data-content of popover-->(Bootstrap)

I have provided html   anchor tags inside the data-content="" attribute of popover button.

Below is a link which upon clicking will show the popover content. The data content inside the popover has one upload and one download link.
Now I want to perform click action on the upload and download link. How can I do that?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#" 
            data-toggle="popover-upload" 
            data-trigger="focus" 
            data-placement="bottom" 
            title="" 
            data-content="<div class='link-Updown'>
                <a href='' class='upload' title='Upload the Zip file here' 
                style=&quot margin: 7px;margin-bottom: 7px;display:block;&quot>Upload</a>

                <a href='' title='Download' 
                style=&quot margin: 7px;margin-bottom: 7px;display:block;&quot>Download</a></div>" 

            style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px;color: darkslategrey;font-weight: bolder" ><i>Upload/Download</i>

        </a>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="popover-upload"]').popover({html:true})
                    .on("click",function(){});
            })            
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're listening to clicks on the container element instead of the anchor tags within the popover content.

You could do something like this:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover-upload"]').popover({
         html:true
    }).parent().on('click', '.link-Updown a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // do your thing

    });
```

You could distinguish between clicks on Upload or Download by giving them a data attribute `data-action` which you can read with `$(this).data('action')`.

See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joyzrw3e/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the popover content is inserted dynamically. This means that on init the html is not present in the DOM so no click event can be attached yet.

To solve this you can [delegate the event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by making a parent element listen to the event:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover-upload" data-content="
<div class='link-Updown'>
  <a href='#'>Upload</a>
  <a href='#'>Download</a>
</div>">
  Upload/Download
</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover-upload"]').popover({ html: true });

  // delegate click event from the document
  $(document).on("click", ".link-Updown a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("download or upload clicked")
  })
});
</script>
```